# How do I share an ethernet connection via wifi on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

I have a Windows 8 laptop that is connected to a router via Ethernet. I want to make the laptop act like a wireless router via wifi so that other devices could connect to the computer using wifi and gain access to its Ethernet internet connection.

How do I do something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short of it... from Redmondpie comes an [article](http://www.redmondpie.com/turn-any-windows-8-pc-into-a-wireless-hotspot-the-easy-way-with-these-handy-apps/) on setting up your Windows 8 computer as a wireless hotspot.  Essentially it tells you to use one of two apps... [Connecfity Hotspot](http://www.connectify.me/hotspot/) and [WiFi Hotspot Creator](http://www.wifihotspotcreator.com/download.html)

Do you need to read the article?  Nope.  Are the Apps a quick and easy way to do this?  Yep.  So, can it be done?  Yep.

Answer (score 3):

Using apps is handy but if you know how to play around in command console, then use the following method:

- Open up a new Notepad document and save these lines into it:

  **netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=VirtualRouter key=routerPassword**

  **netsh wlan start hostednetwork**

Here 'ssid' is the new WiFi network and 'key' refers to password (i.e. they are user defined). Save the file as StartVirtualNet.cmd

- Again open a new doc and save the following line to it:

  **netsh wlan stop hostednetwork**

  Save the file as StopVirtualNet.cmd

Now whenever you want to start or stop Virtual Router use the saved command scripts.

Comment: In which versions of Windows does this procedure work? Only in Win8?

Answer (score 1):

From [Addictivetips](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-create-wireless-ad-hoc-internet-connection-in-windows-8/)

> Apart from Start Orb and classic Start Menu, what most Windows 7 users, who decided to take Windows 8 for a spin, miss in Windows 8 is ability to create ad-hoc network. If you’re a power users, you might’ve noticed that Windows 8 doesn’t include an option to create and setup ad hoc network connection to share files and internet with Wi-Fi enabled computers and devices. Windows 7 ad hoc connection feature does nothing except creating a shared connection with separate IP address to register the device on the virtual network. This allows users to use router’s default or specified DNS server address to easily connect to internet. Even though Windows 8 comes with ICS (Internet Connection Sharing) feature to allow devices  to connect to yours PC internet connection, it doesn’t allow creating a wireless network connection to share the internet. In this post, we will look at some tools that let you easily create and manage ad-hoc connections in Windows 8.

The tips are so long and in so detail..
[Click this link](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-create-wireless-ad-hoc-internet-connection-in-windows-8/) to see the details