# How can I share my internet connection with other devices in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, hotspot, connection-sharing

I am staying at a hotel with very poor WiFi connectivity. There is a wired ethernet connection available in the room, but I obviously can't use that with my phone. Is there any way I can share the connection from my Windows 10 laptop to my phone using my laptop's wireless card? [This method for Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/539699/how-do-i-share-an-ethernet-connection-via-wifi-on-windows-8) doesn't seem to work on Windows 10 anymore. There are some commercial applications out there which purport to do this, but I'd like to do it just with built-in Windows features if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this ability is now built into Windows 10, and is actually much more user-friendly than it was in Windows 7. It's called Mobile Hotspot, and most WiFi cards should be supported. You can share an ethernet connection, a WiFi connection that your laptop is attached to, or even a mobile hotspot if your device has one built in.

1. Open the Start menu (Win key or click the lower left corner of the screen)
2. Type `hotspot`
3. Click on "Change mobile hotspot settings"

   [image: Hotspot settings in start menu]
4. Select the internet connection you want to share from the dropdown menu (there may only be one choice).
5. Click EDIT to set the SSID and password for the WiFi network you are creating.
6. Toggle the sharing to ON.

   [image: Windows 10 hotspot settings]
7. Wait a moment while it configures the network. You should soon be able to see the selected SSID on other mobile devices. When you connect a device, it will appear in the device list on the hotspot settings page. You can connect up to 8 devices at once.